# What networking standard defines how two computers directly connected via Ethernet, ought to interact?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I'm specifically refering to a scenario where there is no router or switch, and the two machines are connected via a single crossover ethernet cable.

I am trying to understand what must happen before the two machines can establish a connection, auto-negotiation, ip assignment and things of that nature.

I have been unable, however, after a rudimentary google and wikipedia search, to determine a standard which defines this behaviour? I am not sure which ISO layer to look at, to find answers?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Refine your search with the keyword `ad-hoc`.

Comment: The question is difficult to answer as written, because there *is* no single standard nor single unified "behaviour" – you're probably missing the whole idea behind layering, which is separation of duties. (Ethernet doesn't know about IP addresses, IP doesn't know about crossover cables, and so on.) I think researching which layers handle which functions should be your first priority.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the machine needs an IP address and a subnet mask. Ideally, the subnet masks should match to such a degree that they can talk to each other.

There is no single "standard" that describes how that has to happen. It's even different for IPv4 and IPv6.

Options include static addresses, link local addresses, or one machine running a DHCP server, and the other a DHCP client. There are probably more options.

Answer (score -1):

The scenario I layed out in my question is known as an ad-hoc network as pointed out by @sawdust.
https://www.comptia.org/content/guides/what-is-an-ad-hoc-network

> Connecting two computers does not always require a centrally managed network. Instead, users can set up an ad hoc network between two computers. The two devices communicate through an ethernet cable or wireless cards.

Wikipedia has an entry for this, although it only covers wireless configurations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network

In addition:

> The term "Ad Hoc" seems to have completely different meanings in
> different contexts.
>
> In wireless LAN context "Ad Hoc" means that all devices in the network
> have the same role. The opposite is an "Infrastructure network" where
> one device has a special role. The data format (OSI layer 2) is
> slightly different in both types of networks.
> https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55465/are-ad-hoc-networks-always-wireless